# Why is target encoder encoding some values as NaN?

Tags: python

I am using a target encoder from category_encoders to encode a feature, here is the code I m using:

```
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder
def encode_large_features(features, X_train, X_test, y_train):
    print('target encoding features ...')
    for _ in features:
        target_encoder = TargetEncoder(_)
        target_encoder.fit(X_train[_], y_train)
        name = _ + '_encoded'
        X_train[name] = target_encoder.transform(X_train[_])
        X_train.drop([_], axis=1, inplace=True)
        X_test[name] = target_encoder.transform(X_test[_])
        X_test.drop([_], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return X_train, X_test
```

the target encoder encodes some values as NaN and I dont know why? here is an example:

[image]

Comment: @wjandrea - found any fix for this? I am facing the same

Comment: could you please provide your input data?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue: [Raised Issue n Repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders/issues/340)

Found a workaround by Building a Custom KFold-Target Encoder which is better than the library version. KFold Target Encoder is less susceptible to data leakage / fewer chances of overfitting.

This will not return NaN in the training Dataset like `category_encoder` library.

> Below example: chid is a categorical column apply KFoldTargetEncoder on it.

Libraries required:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn import base
```

Training Dataset:

```
class KFoldTargetEncoderTrain(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self, colnames,targetName,n_fold=5,verbosity=True,discardOriginal_col=False):

    self.colnames = colnames
    self.targetName = targetName
    self.n_fold = n_fold
    self.verbosity = verbosity
    self.discardOriginal_col = discardOriginal_col

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self


def transform(self,X):

    assert(type(self.targetName) == str)
    assert(type(self.colnames) == str)
    assert(self.colnames in X.columns)
    assert(self.targetName in X.columns)

    mean_of_target = X[self.targetName].mean()
    kf = KFold(n_splits = self.n_fold, shuffle = False, random_state=2019)

    col_mean_name = self.colnames + '_' + 'Kfold_Target_Enc'
    X[col_mean_name] = np.nan

    for tr_ind, val_ind in kf.split(X):
        X_tr, X_val = X.iloc[tr_ind], X.iloc[val_ind]
        X.loc[X.index[val_ind], col_mean_name] = X_val[self.colnames].map(X_tr.groupby(self.colnames)[self.targetName].mean())

    X[col_mean_name].fillna(mean_of_target, inplace = True)

    if self.verbosity:

        encoded_feature = X[col_mean_name].values
        print('Correlation between the new feature, {} and, {} is {}.'.format(col_mean_name,
                                                                                  self.targetName,
                                                                                  np.corrcoef(X[self.targetName].values, encoded_feature)[0][1]))
    if self.discardOriginal_col:
        X = X.drop(self.targetName, axis=1)
        

    return X
```

Fit_Transform on Training Data:

```
targetc_chid = KFoldTargetEncoderTrain('chid','target',n_fold=5)
train_df = targetc_chid.fit_transform(train_df)
```

Test Dataset:

```
class KFoldTargetEncoderTest(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self,train,colNames,encodedName):
        
        self.train = train
        self.colNames = colNames
        self.encodedName = encodedName
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,X):
        mean =  self.train[[self.colNames,
                self.encodedName]].groupby(
                                self.colNames).mean().reset_index() 

        dd = {}
        for row in tqdm(mean.itertuples(index=False)):
            dd[row[0]] = row[1]
        X[self.encodedName] = X[self.colNames]
        X[self.encodedName] = X[self.encodedName].map(dd.get)
        return X
```

Fit on Test Data:

```
test_targetc_chid = KFoldTargetEncoderTest(train_df,'chid','chid_Kfold_Target_Enc')
valid_df = test_targetc_chid.fit_transform(valid_df)
```